# Multiplying values in Excel 2010 (Same cell)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Another excel question. I'm using Excel 2010.

If for example I have a value in cell A1, lets say 2.59

What I want to do is multiply that cell by 1.333 but in the **same** cell

I don't want to have to put a formula in B1 such as =(A1*1.333), because I already have a value in B1 and I don't want to have to insert a new column.

if I highlight cell A1 and put the formula =(A1*1.333) into it the value becomes 0.00

Can what I'm asking be done? or would I need to create a macro?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I wondered this myself, I never found a way so my answer is no (although I am happy to be proved wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below VBA macro appears to work:

```
Public Sub Convert()
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Selection
        If Not IsError(Cell) Then Cell = Cell *1.333
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

If you can spare 1 cell somewhere else in the worksheet/book, you can type `1.333` in that cell, copy that cell and then select A1, "Paste Special" > "Multiply".

This works for multiple selections to multiply :)

After that, delete the cell containing `1.333`.

Answer (score -1):

try this macro

```
Sub multiply()
ActiveCell = ActiveCell * 1.333 
End Sub
```

Comment: why -1 for the macro

Comment: That works great for one cell! Thanks alot! If there were several cells that i've selected how would i write the macro then? As the one you gave I would need to do it one by one.

Comment: you need to put that in the question